# IndexError Python

Tags: python-2.7, split

I currently am strugling with a problem for my school project, if anyone could help me with it Python is constantly giving IndexError, i have tried serveral different options but no luck so far, i need to split the file content "email@domain.com:company" into "email:company", this does the work, but after some lines i will recieve index error, my code:

```
for i in inputs:
    c=i.split(":")
    quee.put((c[0].split('@')[1],c[0],c[1]))
```

## Anoter version:

```
for i in inputs:
    user = i.split(':')[0]
    company = i.split(':')[1]
    user = user.lower()
    quee.put((user.split('@')[1], user[0], company[1]))


for i in inputs:
    user = i.split(':')[0]
    company = i.split(':')[1]
    user = user.lower()
    quee.put((user.split('@')[1], user, company))
```

## Error

File "w.py", line 431, in

```
quee.put((user.split('@')[1], user, company))
```

IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

It's working well for me.

What I think is that the fault lies in your input. There could be some faulty email addresses which either do not have an @ in them or do not have any character before or after the @

Comment: Anyway i could skip this error? i had cleaned the list of improper lines, but it still showing the same.

Comment: If you can view your data, what you could do is - select a subset of the data to make sure that the included email addresses are valid, i.e. they should have a set of characters before @, a set of characters after @ and a set of characters at the end after :
Try running the piece of code on that subset of input